# Android/Eclipse: This LinearLayout layout or its RelativeLayout parent is possibly useless

Tags: android, eclipse, android-layout

I am getting the following warning in Android Application Projet on Eclipse:

`This LinearLayout layout or its RelativeLayout parent is possibly useless`

Can't figure out what problem is. Read other forums but they didn't help. Any ideas?

Here's the code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:gravity="top" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/lin_progress_bar"
        android:layout_width="200dp"
        android:layout_height="65dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="60dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="150dp"
        android:visibility="invisible" >

        <ProgressBar
            android:id="@+id/ProgressBar01"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
        </ProgressBar>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/TextView01"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_marginLeft="30dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:gravity="center_vertical"
            android:text="@string/loading"
            android:textColor="#808080"
            android:textSize="17sp"
            android:textStyle="bold" >
        </TextView>
    </LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: It's really useless to have thos two nested containers. I'd remove the LinearLayout (I always prefer RelativeLayouts).

Comment: Don't use hard-coded `layout_width`s and `layout_height`s. Your app will run on a variety of devices and you might not always get the same look if you use hard-coded values. Try using the standard `match_parent` and `wrap_content` and layout_weights as much as possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the simplified version of your layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    >
    <ProgressBar
        android:id="@+id/ProgressBar01"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="60dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="150dp"
        android:visibility="invisible"
    />
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/TextView01"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginLeft="30dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:text="@string/loading"
        android:textColor="#808080"
        android:textSize="17sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
    />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Now it has gained in flatness - which translates is better performances

Answer (score 0):

The error message means that the RelativeLayout contains a LinearLayout which contains the actual widgets: It would be more efficient to remove the Relative Layout and use only the LinearLayout.

Note that this is a warning and you sometimes you do need a useless layout to get your app to look the way you want to (though I haven't encountered many of these situations).